# Qt MessageBox remove TitleBar?

Tags: qt

How to remove Title Bar from Qt MessageBox in Qt?

I have gone through

```
QMessageBox::QMessageBox(Icon icon, const QString & title, const QString & text, StandardButtons buttons, QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
```

But how to use this. Any example?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the constructor of QMessageBox. You use it like any other construcor, for example:

```
QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Question,
                   "This is the title", 
                   "This is the text", 
                   QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No, this,
                   Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
msgBox.exec();
```

or

```
QMessageBox* msgBox = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Question,
                                      "This is the title", 
                                      "This is the text", 
                                      QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No, this,
                                      Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
msgBox->exec();
```

In this case, `this` is a parent window (`QMainWindow` instance)

Answer (score 0):

In the `Qt::WindowFlags f` parameter, you can pass option that tells how to decorate the dialog window.

Qt::Windows flag is a | separated list of [`Qt::WindowType`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#WindowType-enum).
By default, a dialog get the `Qt::Dialog` type. If you want to change it, you can try the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` value to remove completely the title bar and frame arround your dialog. Trying other options might get you want you expect.

Comment: No, the default value is `Qt::Dialog | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Qt::Sheet` is better in my case. It is totally mac style...
`QtMessageBox::information` will give you `Qt::Dialog` style under mac.